Unable to import federated module into another project
I'm attempting to use Module Federation to share a module from one project (remote app) to another project (host app).
In my remote app, the module is compiled successfully, and I can see the federated configuration in /assets/remoteconfig.js. However, when I try to import this federated module into my host app, I encounter the error "Cannot find module 'remoteModuleName'".
Here's what I've done:
Configured the remote app using Module Federation. The federated module is exposed with a name (remoteModuleName) and a URL (/assets/remoteconfig.js).
In the host app, I've set up the federation configuration to point to the URL of the remote module.
Attempted to import the federated module in the host app using import('remoteModuleName').
Despite these steps, I'm still unable to import the federated module into my host app. The error message suggests that the module cannot be found.
I've double-checked the URL, ensured that the remote app is running, and verified that the federated configuration is correct. However, I'm unable to resolve this issue.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem with Module Federation? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
This is my vite.config.js for remote app
export default defineConfig({
    base: './',
    plugins: [
        react(), 
        federation({
            name: 'MicroApp',
            filename: 'MicroApp.js',
            exposes: {
                'App': './src/App.tsx',
            },
            shared: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom'],
       }),
        ,viteTsconfigPaths()],
    server: {    
        open: true,
        port: 3001, 
    },
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: 'esnext',
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false
      }
})

this is my vite.config.js for host app

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    
    return {
        plugins: [
            federation({
                name: 'host-app',
                remotes: {
                    MicroApp: "http://localhost:3006/assets/MicroApp.js",
                },
                shared: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom'],
            }),
            react(),
            svgr(),
            macrosPlugin(),
            viteStaticCopy({
                // config
            }),
            viteStaticCopy({
                // config
            }),
        ],
        envPrefix: 'REACT_APP_',
        build: {
            outDir: 'dist',
        },
    };
});

Component file
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const MicroApp = lazy(() => import('MicroApp/App'));

export function Datagraph() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={ <>Loading...</>}>
        <MicroApp />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}


error : Cannot find module 'MicroApp/App' or its corresponding type declarations.
